# How to test a second parameter in a PHPUnit mock object

Tags: php, phpunit

This is what I have:

```
$observer = $this->getMock('SomeObserverClass', array('method'));
$observer->expects($this->once())
         ->method('method')
         ->with($this->equalTo($arg1));
```

But the method should take two parameters. I am only testing that the first parameter is being passed correctly (as $arg1).

How do test the second parameter?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I believe the way to do this is:

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
     ->method('method')
     ->with($this->equalTo($arg1),$this->equalTo($arg2));
```

Or

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
     ->method('method')
     ->with($arg1, $arg2);
```

If you need to perform a different type of assertion on the 2nd arg, you can do that, too:

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
     ->method('method')
     ->with($this->equalTo($arg1),$this->stringContains('some_string'));
```

If you need to make sure some argument passes multiple assertions, use logicalAnd()

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
     ->method('method')
     ->with($this->logicalAnd($this->stringContains('a'), $this->stringContains('b')));
```

Comment: I ran into this a couple weeks ago. Using:
    ->with($this->equalTo($foo, $bar)

Worked for me.

Comment: @ieure The second argument to equalTo() is $delta, so that probably doesn't do what you think it does.